# jquery UI: dialog closes immediately when opened with space bar

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

As the Title explains, when a keydown- or keypress-handler on space-bar opens a dialog  that contains a button that gets autofocus which closes the dialog (a default ok button), then the button is triggered on keyup.

Here is a [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/IARI/y3Hqu/)

```
var dialog = $('#d').dialog({ 
    autoOpen: false, 
    buttons: [{text:"ok", click: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }}] 
});

$(window).keydown(function (event) {
    if (event.which==32 || event.which==13) {
        console.log("TEST");
        dialog.dialog("open");
    } else console.log(event.which);
});
```

In fact, my Problem is the same as in this Question:
[jquery-ui-dialog-closes-immediately-when-opened-with-onkeypress-enter-space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1505580/jquery-ui-dialog-closes-immediately-when-opened-with-onkeypress-enter-space)
However, I want to open the dialog on keydown (or keypress), not on keyup, as suggested in the accepted solution. Also I do not want to change the autofocus to another element, i.e. a second space-bar should in fact close the dialog.

Comment: The fiddle works for me. http://jsfiddle.net/y3Hqu/6/

Comment: Thanks, but note the last sentence in my Question :)

Answer (score 0):

Added `$('button.ui-button').blur();`

`JS Code`

```
$(window).keydown(function(event) {
    if (event.which == 32 || event.which == 13) {
        console.log("TEST");
        dialog.dialog("open");
        $('button.ui-button').blur();
    } else
        console.log(event.which);
});
```

Updated [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/y3Hqu/1/)

Comment: Thanks, but this is just disabling the focus - note the last sentence in my Question: a second space bar should close the dialog.